# Extract last two digits from a column and convert to year in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `MyTable` in the MSSQL database. Column A always includes a numerical value but in varchar form; the last two digits are always the year. For instance, a value in column A is 12051515241501 refers to 2001, or 1201551521 refers to the 2021 year. My question is can I create and show one more computed column as a year?

Input

| Column |
| --- |
| 10515121 |
| 05111512 |
| 23334305 |

Expected result:

| Column | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 10515121 | 2021 |
| 05111512 | 2012 |
| 23334305 | 2005 |

Comment: what datatype has your column?

Comment: I updated the question. The column A is varchar.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to save date in a date column, so that time costly conversions are unnecessary

```
select 
  Convert(varchar(4), 
  Cast('01/01/'+ RIGHT([Column], 2) as  datetime) ,120) as yyyyCol
FROM Table1
```

| yyyyCol |
| --- |
| 2021 |
| 2012 |
| 2005 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pbKOMmAc)